# Cannot figure out how to properly increment a variable inside of a while loop, C

Tags: c, while-loop, cs50

EDIT: After re-writing my code in my IDE, for the 8th time today, I have made rookie mistake of giving my inputs a false data type, that has been fixed but my outputs still are incorrect.

Details about my goal: When making change, odds are you want to minimize the number of coins you’re dispensing for each customer.
Well, suppose that a cashier owes a customer some change and in that cashier’s drawer are quarters (25¢), dimes (10¢), nickels (5¢), and pennies (1¢). The problem to be solved is to decide which coins and how many of each to hand to the customer.

Expected Result: 
Change owed: 0.41
4


Actual result:
Change owed: 0.41
3

```
#include <math.h>
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void)

{
    float dollars;
    int changeowed = 0;

    do
    {
      dollars = get_float ("Change owed: ");
    }
    while (dollars < 0);

    float cents = round(dollars * 100);

    while (cents >= 25)
    {
        cents = cents - 25;
        changeowed++;
    }

    while (cents > 10)
    {
        cents = cents - 10;
        changeowed++;
    }
    while (cents > 5)
    {
        cents = cents - 5;
        changeowed++;
    }

        while (cents > 1)
        {
            cents = cents - 1;
            changeowed++;
        }

        printf("%i \n", changeowed);
}
```

Comment: How do you expect `int dollar;` to store `0.41`?

Comment: `int dollars = get_float ("Change owed: ");`. types mismatch...

Comment: The simplest approach to solving this would be to run in a debugger and look at variables like dollars and cents.  If you are unwilling to learn the debugger, you could do the same thing more slowly by adding print statements at various points in the program.

Comment: Tom, by "keep the value in an integer (the number of cents)" did you mean to declare my "coins" variable to an int data type instead of what now is a float? I have done so: int cents = round(dollars * 100);

And my output for 0.41 is still 3 amount of coins. Did I miss something?

Comment: @TomKarzes While what you're saying is true for real applications, it does not really matter for a cs50 course

Comment: @Nermin Ok you were right, floating point was not the issue here.  I found your problem and posted a solution as an answer.

Comment: @Nermin better use integer. `unsigned cents = dollars * 100;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the problem:  There are 4 loops, one for quarters, one for dimes, one for nickels, and one for pennies.  The first loop condition is correct:

```
while (cents >= 25)
```

The other three are incorrect:

```
while (cents > 10)
while (cents > 5)
while (cents > 1)
```

These all need to be changed to use `>=` in place of `>`.

Comment: Tom, thanks a lot for your time. Your answers helped me get to the finish. I have upvoted you but since I have less than 15 rep so it might not be visible. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

you can do it much simple for any nominals. Use integer types.

```
int nominals[] = {100, 25, 10, 5, 1, 0};

void getNominals(double money, int *result)
{
    unsigned ncents = money * 100.0;
    int *nm = nominals;
    while(*nm && ncents)
    {
        *result++ = ncents / *nm;
        ncents %= *nm++;
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    int result[sizeof(nominals) / sizeof(nominals[0])] = {0};

    getNominals(4.36, result);

    for(size_t index = 0; nominals[index]; index++)
    {
        printf("%d = %d\n", nominals[index], result[index]);
    }
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/WdYxxr